# Remove selected row from DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hi guys i had been researching for two days about how to delete a selected row in wpf datagrid but i found nothing useful .I used `PreviewKeyDown` event handler below but all in vain.I just want to remove the row selected by the user.
I am MVVM pattern and my code is :

```
  public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; }
     vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>();
      public ICommand AddVlan
        {
          get
          {
            if (_addVlan == null)
              _addVlan = new RelayCommand(() => this.AddVlans());

            return _addVlan;
          }

        }

     public ICommand RemoveVlan
        {
            get
            {
                if (_removeVlan == null)
                    _removeVlan = new RelayCommand(() => this.RemoveVlans());

                return _removeVlan;
            }

        }
   void AddVlans()
    {
          Console.WriteLine("Add vlan");
            var serial = new VLANSPropertyClass();
            serial.S_No = vlan.Count + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(serial.S_No);
            serial.vname = VlanName;
            Console.WriteLine(serial.vname);
            serial.vid = VlanID;
            Console.WriteLine(serial.vid);
            serial.ip = VlanIP1 + "." + VlanIP2 + "." + VlanIP3 + "." + VlanIP4;
            Console.WriteLine(serial.ip);
            serial.vports = SelectedVlanPort;
            vlan.Add(serial);
        }
     void RemoveVlans()
        {
            var rem = new VLANSPropertyClass();
            rem.S_No = vlan.Remove();
            rem.vname = vlan.Remove();
            rem.ip = vlan.Remove();

        }
```

Can any one provide me the solution to this problem.Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: Bind the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` to a relevant property in your ViewModel. Then create an `InputBinding` to a relevant `Command` in your ViewModel, then in the command execution code, simply remove the SelectedItem from the ObservableCollection. Oh, and BTW, delete all this horrible code and use proper DataBinding. WPF is not winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you use the MVVM design pattern in WPF programs.  Your `DataGrid` control's `ItemsSource` property is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of objects.  To remove a row from the `DataGrid`, all you have to do is remove the object from the `ObservableCollection`.

If you don't know what "MVVM" means, here's an [MSDN article about the Model View View-Model Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821028.aspx).

**EDIT**

I am responding to your comment in here since the response requires more space than a comment will hold.

You didn't include any XAML in your question, so I'm going to assume you've got something like this for your `DataGrid` definition:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=vlan}"
          . . .>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        . . .
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

First, your view model needs a property of type `VLANSPropertyClass` to hold the item that's currently selected in the `DataGrid`:

```
public VLANSPropertyClass SelectedVlan {
    get { return iSelectedVlan; }
    set { 
        iSelectedVlan = value;
        OnPropertyChanged ("SelectedVlan" );
    }
}
private VLANSPropertyClass iSelectedVlan = null;
```

Next, you have to modify your XAML to bind the new property to the `DataGrid's SelectedItem` property:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=vlan}"
          SelectedValue={Binding Path=SelectedVlan}"
          . . .>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        . . .
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then, your `RemoveVlans` method should look something like:

```
void RemoveVlans() {
    if ( SelectedVlan != null ) {
        vlans.Remove( SelectedVlan );
        SelectedVlan = null;
    }
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: ..Now i added my actual code which i wrote using MVVM now i think you saying thai need to modify my RemoveVLAN() method?

Comment: Can you also suggest me the way of storing every row of my datagrid in any of the data-structure like List,ArrayList,Queue,Stack,Dictionary etc.and every row stores like a separate object.Or any other way which you like to suggest?

Comment: As I said in my answer, use an `ObservableCollection`.  An `ObservableCollection` essentially is a `List` that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  When you bind a collection that implements that interface to a property like `ItemsSource`, the collection notifies WPF whenever you change it.  WPF then uses that notification to update the display automatically. In the XAML for the `DataGrid's` columns, you bind each column to a property of the class that is in the `ObservableCollection's` type parameter. (continued)

Comment: If you need to keep an array of objects in a property of the class in the `ObservableCollection's` type parameter, and you want to use the `DataGrid's RowDetails` feature to display that data in a nested `DataGrid`, make that property an `ObservableCollection` of that type & bind it to the nested `DataGrid's ItemsSource` property.